# Using sp_executesql with input and output paramters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Using SQL Server 2016.  I am writing a stored procedure.  I have the following code that is happening inside a `WHILE` loop

```
DELCARE @recordExists int;
SET @recordExistsQuery = 'SELECT @recordExists=COUNT(*) FROM @fullTableName WHERE validFrom <= CAST(@asOfDate as datetime)';
exec sp_executesql @recordExistsQuery, N'@recordExists INT OUT, @fullTableName varchar(60), @asOfdate datetime' @recordExists OUT
```

I get the error `Must declare the table variable @fullTableName however I have already declared and set this variable (prior to the while loop) and used it multiple times prior the while loop so I know it exists and is valid.  It's defined like so -

```
DECLARE @fullTableName varchar(60);
SET @fullTableName = (SELECT CONCAT(@schema, '.', @TableName));
```

and I have it printed prior to the while loop and it looks fine, and I have it printer per loop and that works as well.

What is wrong with my dynamic sql here?  I am trying to use the paramterization method instead of string building with quotes as I am dealing with a datetime and want to do that with better practices than a bunch of quotes.  Is that possible?  How can I rewrite

```
SET @recordExistsQuery = 'SELECT @recordExists=COUNT(*) FROM @fullTableName WHERE validFrom <= CAST(@asOfDate as datetime)';
exec sp_executesql @recordExistsQuery, N'@recordExists INT OUT, @fullTableName varchar(60), @asOfdate datetime' @recordExists OUT
```

so that it works as expected?

UPDATE:  Hardcoding the tablename instead of passing it as a parameter worked.  I am now getting the following error from the following code -

```
SET @recordExistsQuery = 'SELECT @recordExists=COUNT(*) FROM ' + @fullTableName + ' WHERE validFrom<=CAST(@asOfDate as datetime)';
PRINT @recordExistsQuery
exec sp_executesql @recordExistsQuery, N'@asOfDate datetime, @recordExists INT OUT', @recordExistsOut`
```

The print statement shows

```
SELECT @recordExists=COUNT(*) FROM [MySchema].[MyTable] WHERE validFrom<=(@asOfDate as datetime)
```

The error I now get is

```
Msg 8162, Level 16, State 2, Line 0
The formal parameter "@asOfDate" was not declared as an OUTPUT paramter, but the actual paramter passed in requested output.
```

I have `@asOfDate` as a paramter of my stored proecedure defined as
`@asOfDate DATETIME=NULL` and the first line of my sp sets a default value if none is passed in

```
IF @asOfdate IS NULL 
    SET @asOfDate = GETDATE();
```

Anyone know what is going wrong now?

UPDATE 2:
Using this line instead

```
'SELECT @recordExists=COUNT(*) FROM '+ @fullTableName +' WHERE validFrom <= CAST('+@asOfDate'+' as datetime)'
```

Now gets me the error `Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

@asOfDate is defined as a paramter of my sp like `@asOfDate datetime=NULL` and initialized to `getdate()`.  I am testing this with @asOfDate=null, so it is using getdate() to initialize the value.

Comment: You simply cannot use table names as parameters, you need to build this part of query string beforehand.

Comment: Also, do use `QUOTENAME`: `SELECT @fullTableName = CONCAT(QUOTENAME(@schema), '.', QUOTENAME(@TableName))`. No need for things to gratuitously break on unusual names.

Comment: @Arvo thank you, I did not know that, I was able to get past this error with that information.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Good idea, thank you for that bit of information.  Was not aware of QUOTENAME, am very new to writing logic in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the string like this

```
'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM'+ @fullTableName +'WHERE validFrom <= CAST('+@asOfDate+' as datetime)'
```

since @fullTableName is going as a string and not a variable, it was not working. If you change to the above, the final string will have the table name you wanted

This update should fix the asofdate issue

Also, you need to remove @recordExists and use the response from execution as @recordExists

Comment: Thank you that got me past the first hurdle.  Can you please take a look at the update and let me know if you know what is going wrong now?

Comment: @BrianKarabinchak please check the updated line, I have include asofdate as a variable

Comment: Ok, That now gives me an error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`  Is there an issue with my using `datetime` as the type of @asOfDate, or assigning to `GETDATE()` initially you think?

Comment: Sorry, there was an additional ' in my previous update which I corrected. Can you try with the latest string and give me the output?

Comment: I had caught that extra ' and took care of it.  My query currnetly looks like yours except I have `@recordExists=COUNT(*)` in the select clause, and I have a space after `FROM ` and before ` WHERE` to space the tablename.   Otherwise my query looks just like yours now and the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Could not quite get it to work as it was, so I ended up doing the following - when I initialized the date I also made a formatted version of it -

```
paramters - 
@asOfDate DATETIME=NULL,
...
BEGIN

IF @asOfdate IS NULL
    SET @asOfDate = GETDATE()
DECLARE @asOfDateFormatted NVARCHAR(30);
SET @asOfDateFormatted = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), @asOfDate, 126);
...
Dynamic sql - 
SET @recordExistsQuery = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '+ @fullTableName +' WHERE validFrom <= '''+asOfDateFormatted+'''';
exec sp_executesql @recordExistsQuery, N'@recordExists INT OUT', @recordExists OUT
```

If someone knows a better way please let me know but this is how I got it to work for now.

Comment: `FROM'+ @fullTableName +'WHERE ` Nope that surely did not "work". Perhaps mangled for posting by you need spaces to separate the keywords and the names.

Comment: Yea transposition error copying by hand from a remote vm to here.

Answer (score 0):

When using dynamic SQL, bear in mind the following:

- Table names (and other objects such as columns) cannot be passed as parameters, they must be injected.
- Only do this using `QUOTENAME` to ensure proper escaping
- Object names should be stored in `sysname` (alias for `nvarchar(128)`) and queries in `nvarchar(max)`
- Data should always be passed as parameters, not injected

```sql
DECLARE @asOfDate DATETIME='20210923',

IF @asOfdate IS NULL
    SET @asOfDate = GETDATE();

DECLARE @recordExistsQuery nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT @recordExists = COUNT(*)
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '
WHERE validFrom <= @asOfdate;
';

PRINT @recordExistsQuery; -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql
  @recordExistsQuery,
  N'@recordExists INT OUT, @asOfdate DATETIME',
  @recordExists = @recordExists OUT,
  @asOfdate = @asOfdate;
```